# Basic auth for Webdriverio for headless and headful

Tags: basic-authentication, webdriver-io, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am trying to create a framework for my application with webdriverio and mocha for headless and headful execution. we use basic auth for login (passing username and password in the authentication pop up), tried passing it username and password as a part of url but that is not working for chrome’s new version.any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The credentials-in-URL method has been broken in Chrome based browsers and Safari for a while.  It still works in Firefox, but it pops up an application level dialogue before loading the page and I'm not sure if WebdriverIO can see it.

WebdriverIO has no way of interacting with the HTTPAuth dialog directly.  I badger Christian about this every six months or so, guess I'm due to do that again.  Browserstack's documentation indicates that they do have a way of dealing with it, but I haven't tried it.